# How to automatically get user in django admin through form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form in my django website where the user requests coins and the information is sent to the admin for me to process. I want to automatically get the user who filled the form without them doing it themselves.

Here's the model.py file:

```
class Requestpayment (models.Model):
  username= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null=True)
  useremail= models.CharField(max_length=100)
  accountmail= models.CharField(max_length=100)
  accountphonenumber=models.CharField(max_length=15)
  coinsrequested=models.ForeignKey(Requestamount, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null=True)
  created= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.accountmail
```

the forms.py:

```
class Requestpaymentform (ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Requestpayment
        fields = '__all__'
```

and the views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')   
def redeemcoins (request):
    form = Requestpaymentform
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = Requestpaymentform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
             form = form.save(commit=False)
             username = request.user
             form.save()
             return redirect ('home')
```

I am pretty sure something is wrong but i don't know what it is (I'm very new at django) anyway the form always shows all the users in the website for the current user to pick who they are.

[redeem coins page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfXQM.png)

I also tried excluding that part of the form but it didn't work it just shows up empty in the admin.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign it to the instance wrapped in the form, so:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def redeemcoins(request):
    form = Requestpaymentform()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Requestpaymentform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.username = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    # …
```

It makes more sense however to name this field `user` than `username`. In the model you can also make the `username` field non-editable, such that it does not appear in the form:

```
from django.conf import settings


class Requestpayment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `username= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null=True)`, Django add a field named user_id in your database which allow django to find User object for Requestpayment.

You can use user_id field to add a User object in Requestpayment.

1. You don't need to pass username field in your fields list if you want to get user in view.

   ```
   class Requestpaymentform (ModelForm):
       class Meta:
       model = Requestpayment

       #fields = '__all__'
       fields = ['useremail',
                 'accountmail',
                 'accountphonenumber',
                 'coinsrequested',
                 'created']
   ```
2. Now do this to get user in your view.

   ```
   @login_required(login_url='login')
   def redeemcoins(request):
       form = Requestpaymentform()
       if request.method == 'POST':
           form = Requestpaymentform(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
               requestpayment = form.save(commit=False)
               requestpayment.user_id = request.user.id 
               requestpayment.save()
               return redirect('home')
   ```

And it's great to use **user** instead **username** because it's a User object and not a simple field.

Please for my English !!!